# Doctrine (with Symfony2) only tries connection to DB using root@localhost

Tags: authentication, symfony, doctrine-orm, localhost, root

### **The error:(occurring in the prod env)**

*request.CRITICAL: PDOException: SQLSTATE[28000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES) (uncaught exception) at /srv/inta/current/vendor/doctrine-dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/PDOConnection.php line 36 [] []*

### What I've tried so far

The weird thing is that I actually have access using the root user, and the provided password. Logging in as root via the console works great.

I'm using the following **parameters.yml** file located in *app/config/*

```
parameters:
    database_driver:   pdo_mysql
    database_host:     localhost
    database_port:     ~
    database_name:     int_apartments
    database_user:     root
    database_password: pw goes here

    mailer_transport:  smtp
    mailer_host:       localhost
    mailer_user:       ~
    mailer_password:   ~

    locale:            en
    secret:            ThisTokenIsNotSoSecretChangeIt
```

As you can see, it is quite standard with only the name of the db, user and password changed.

In my **config.yml** located in *app/config* (the relevant portions)

```
imports:
- { resource: security.yml }
- { resource: parameters.yml }

...

doctrine:
   dbal:
      driver:   %database_driver%
      host:     %database_host%
      port:     %database_port%
      dbname:   %database_name%
      user:     %database_user%
      password: %database_password%
      charset:  UTF8
      dbname:   int_apartments

  orm:
      auto_generate_proxy_classes: %kernel.debug%
      auto_mapping: true
      mappings:
          StofDoctrineExtensionsBundle: false
```

Now, I wanted to start at "step 1" and verify that the parameters.yml file is actually being imported, so I changed the host to "localhos" or the user to "tom" or whatever and the error message located in *app/logs/prod.log* stays exact as is - the location doesn't change and the user doesn't change.

So I checked my **config_prod.yml** located in *app/config*

```
imports:
- { resource: config.yml }


#doctrine:
#    metadata_cache_driver: apc
#    result_cache_driver: apc
#    query_cache_driver: apc

monolog:
    handlers:
        main:
            type:         fingers_crossed
            action_level: error
            handler:      nested
        nested:
            type:  stream
            path:  %kernel.logs_dir%/%kernel.environment%.log
            level: debug
```

...and everything seems standard!

### Summary of what's going on

So here is the quick version.

- Authentication error exists for root@localhost
- Verified my authentication creditials by logging in as that user via the console
- Want to check if the parameters.yml file is being loaded
- Changed some values - none affected the error message

**(small)Edit:**
What I actually want to do is to connect to the DB as a completely different user with a different password. Even when I enter different credentials into my parameters.yml file, doctrine still spits out the "root@localhost" error.

Ideas?

Comment: Does your password contain any special characters?

Comment: The password is only A-z 0-9 currently

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Silly mistake, seems due to a bad user/group/owner configuration on the server.

the app/cache directory is owned by "root", but when I run 
    app/console cache:clear --env=prod --no-debug
I am running as another user (not root). So there were issues in clearing the cache and doctrine seems to have been using a very old configuration located in the cache files.

Lessons learned:

- Always try running as root (as a last resort)
- Use a properly configured web server to avoid ownership issues

Comment: Yes! Please cache:clear! The doctrine is caching the credentials somewhere. I tried so many things and this simple fix did it. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I solved my problem by renaming the prod folder i uploaded to prod_old because the system could not delete the folder for some reason.